# Ngram with counts in the below desired output

Tags: python, n-gram

the following got me to this below output:

```
        words   freq
0        hello   5
1        yes     10


I would like the above output to be same for ngrams(4). The results is only showing freq with "1". Can someone help me tune the codes for ngrams and as per the above output. The requirement is Ngrams with freqencies and output in excel(xlsx).
```

Examples shown below:

```
 (('benito', 'kanchan'), 1),
 (('kanchan', 'tata'), 1),
 (('tata', 'arora'), 1),

So far the code:

df = pd.read_excel(r"Filename")

#Converting to lovercase
df['Body'] = df['Body'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))
df['Body'].head()

#Count of Words
df['word_count'] = df['Body'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(" ")))
df[['Body','word_count']].head()

#Removing Punctuation
df['Body'] = df['Body'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
df['Body'].head()

#Removing Stop Words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

df['Body'] = df['Body'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop))
df['Body'].head()

#df['Body'] = df['Body'].astype('|S')

# Word Count
tf1 = (df['Body']).apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(" "))).sum(axis = 0).reset_index()
print (tf1)
tf1.columns = ['words','tf']
tf1
```

Ngrams
    from collections import Counter
    from textblob import TextBlob
    a = TextBlob(tf1['words'][0]).ngrams(4)
    a = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in a]
    print (a)
    counter = (Counter (a))
    counter.most_common(150)
    counter.columns = ['ngram','tf']
    counter